# Naming Boolean Variables for Mutually Exclusive options rather than True/False relationship

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm looking for a way to name a boolean variable that represents two mutually exclusive options such that it's clear what the selected option is when the variable is True or when it's False, without looking at the implementation.

As an example, imagine your program chooses between Chicken xor Fish. Currently, in the database, the variable would be named "lChickenOrFish". Looking at just that, it's unclear if lChickenOrFish = True would represent Chicken, or if it would represent Fish. To find out, you would have to open the code and search for where it's used, and interpret from there.

I know you could instead have two variables, lChicken and lFish, but that opens up the possibility of having lChicken = True and lFish = True in the same row, which would be an error, and therefore require code to check for that.

You could also just use lChicken for the name, and have lChicken = 0 implicitly mean Fish. But then, if a programmer needs to know what the other option is, they have to open the code to look it up, which is the same problem as before. And in some cases, it may not even be clear if there is another option to look up, depending on what the boolean is doing.

So is there a way to make that clear for a programmer looking purely at a SQL Server database without looking up the actual implementation in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a boolean, I'd recommend an enum or a string value. With no language specified, I can offer some pseudo code for an enum:

```
enum FoodValue {
  Chicken = 1,
  Fish = 2
}

var dbValue = FoodValue.Chicken;
```

That way if you want to add values later, it is easy to update the enum or store the string value directly.

Comment: Ah - I'm specifically asking about naming entries in a SQL Server database, I'll add that more explicitly in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely possible to do what you're looking to do using a single boolean value. It seems like you'd have to have multiple boolean values and keep them in sync, which is a problem, like you stated. Why is storing a direct value in the database not an option?

Comment: I really just want to rename some existing columns in an old code base, with minimal changes. I figured if I could rename them to be clear, that would be easier than adding new columns or whatever else.

The enum is a good solution, though. If there's not a way to just rename the variable clearly (likely), then this is a good fallback solution.

I didn't ask that question, though, because I figure the general question would be more helpful.